# Mobile app backend

Tags: android, ios, backend

I am a web developer but recently I have been asked to build a backend of a mobile app.So basically there is a single form inside the app and the user fillup the form and hit submit and the data will be sent to a secured server.The app will be made by someone and I just need to get the data from the app and store it in a db.

Now I have few questions like:

1. Do I need to register with apple developer account or some other account like android?
2. Is there any guide or tutorial how to get the data from the app and process it.

Also once the app is made by the developer how can it be downloaded?

Comment: Depending on the requirement and the knowledge of the app developer you can just handle the submitted data as a form post post or if you are more familiar a JSON object can be posted to some URL. which you can than insert in to the database.

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your favorite server-side programming language. (eg. php, ruby....)

- You can create a url where the app can make post requests.
- Tell the app developer that he should send the data in json within the post requests.
  He can send the form data after someone has filled it. Let him add an unique id to every form data, to make sure that you do not save duplicated data.
- When you got the json parse it and push to the DB.

Optional:

- Implement authentication
- Implement encryption

You do not need to have a developer account for that (creating a web service), but respectively the app developer.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out Parse: http://parse.com. Could save you some work?

Comment: Or Kii http://developer.kii.com

Answer (score 1):

First thing i want to clear that there is nothing about back end process for web developer. That all thing should have to manage by Mobile Developer.Web Developer just have to get Request and perform action &  return Response base on request.

Doesn't matter that process is running in background or four ground just manage response time. Mean if User didn't get response in such specific time then try to mange that and return appropriate response to user.

If you don't know how make web service then [www.w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) and some other link or example also that will help you.

Start with basic concept and then switch to next step.

Good Example about [Android + PHP : Web service](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)

Good Luck !!

Comment: Thanks Chintan for the link.I will go through it.

Comment: sorry its done now...thanks mate.