# How to create a backend for mobile app

Tags: ios, rest, server, location, backend

How can I create a backend for mobile app where users will be able to POST their location to the server and will be able to GET the users in their surrounding area. Any answers appreciated.

Comment: Check: [Mobile app backend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749989/mobile-app-backend)

Comment: Unfortunately this question is _too broad_. Voted to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as a backend and use the OSS GeoFire to store and request the info you require.

See [This article about GeoFire](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/06/geofire-20.html)

Comment: I started integrating firebase database for swift via cocopods
 and will also integrate geofire to get users in my radius